# How To Do OpenLayers.Mobile Popup

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile, popup

It seems that the OpenLayers.mobile.js library (v 2.12) doesn't have a popup class. Does anyone know how to do a popup with the mobile version?

I'm using some code that i ported over form normal OL web map. When i call new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored i get an undefined error on OpenLayers.Popup class.

It's not in the OpenLayers.mobile.js. I'm lost

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I do that with the 2.13 version, you can try to do the same with 2.12, so if you need to install Python, look at the solution here [Problem creating a popup in mobile openlayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74202/problem-creating-a-popup-in-mobile-openlayer)